# Inserting TIMESTAMP data in MYSQL? Error "MYSQL version for the right syntax to use near etc"

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, timestamp

I want to add a Timestamp data in my table but got error how can I fix this?

[image]

Here is my Proc

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `db`.`AddMerchantProcessor` (m_id INT, p_id INT, d TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tbl_merchant_processor`(`merchant_id`, `processor_id`, `date`) VALUES(m_id, p_id, d);
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timestamp should be wrap with single quotes, eg

```
CALL AddMerchantProcessor(0, 1, '2012-01-01 00:00:00')
```

but it's not the proper way of using the `Command` object. The query should be parameterized.

Here's a little code snippet:

```
MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand();
comm.Connection = cn;
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.CommandText = "AddMerchantProcessor";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("m_id", m_id);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_id", p_id);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", d);
cn.Open();
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

you need to:

- use `using` statement for automatic object disposal
- put some `trycatch` for proper exception handling

SOURCES

- [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)
- [Add (*preferred method to be used*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx)
- [Command Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Try-Catch Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried this already and still got error "Incorrect datetime value: '12/28/2012 17:36:19' for column 'd' at row 1"

Comment: it's fix , I just added Convert.ToDateTime(d). Thanks